# Calculus Reduction Formula

Tags: calculus, integration, reduction-formula

> For any integer $k > 0$, show the reduction formula
>   $$\int^{2}_{-2} x^{2k} \sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx = C_k \int^{2}_{-2} x^{2k-2} \sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx$$
>   for some constant $C_{k}$.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/885U3.png))

I thought this would be fairly straightforward but im a little confused. Do I start out by doing a trig substitution?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can always define $$C_k = \dfrac{\displaystyle \int_{-2}^2 x^{2k} \sqrt{4-x^2}dx}{\displaystyle \int_{-2}^2 x^{2k-2} \sqrt{4-x^2}dx}$$ since the denominator is non-zero.

Comment: i would like to find the reduction formula but im not sure how to start the integration

Comment: The substitution $\sin\theta \ = \ \frac{x}{2}$ leads to... (Do you get a trigonometric integral you can handle?)

Answer (score 2):

Let $I_k = \displaystyle \int^{2}_{-2} x^{2k} \sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx$.

Let $u = x^{2k-1}$ and $dv = x\sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx$.

We then have $du = (2k-1)x^{2k-2} \, dx$ and

$\begin{align*}
v &= \int x\sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx\\
&=\displaystyle -\frac{1}{3} (4-x^2)^{3/2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{3}(4-x^2)\sqrt{4-x^2}\end{align*}$

Applying integration by parts $\left (\int u \, dv = uv - \int v \, du \right )$:

$$\begin{align*}
I_k&= \left [ x^{2k-1} \times -\frac{1}{3}\overbrace{(4-x^2)^{3/2}}^{\text{this term becomes 0}} \right ]^{2}_{-2} + \frac{1}{3}(2k-1)\int^{2}_{-2} x^{2k-2}(4-x^2)\sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx\\
&= 0 + \frac{1}{3}(2k-1)\int^{2}_{-2}4x^{2k-2}\sqrt{4-x^2} - x^{2k}\sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx\\
&= \frac{4}{3}(2k-1)\overbrace{\int^{2}_{-2}4x^{2k-2}\sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx}^{I_{k-1}} - \frac{1}{3}(2k-1) \overbrace{\int^{2}_{-2} - x^{2k}\sqrt{4-x^2} \, dx}^{I_k}\\[10pt]
\therefore 3I_k &= 4(2k-1)I_{k-1} - (2k-1)I_{k}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Rearranging yields $I_k = \displaystyle \frac{4k-2}{k+1}I_{k-1}$, so

$$C_k = \displaystyle \frac{4k-2}{k+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It took a little time to check through this, but here is an approach using the substitution I'd proposed in the comments.  Applying $\ \sin\theta = \frac{x}{2}$ , we have

$$\int_{-2}^{2} x^{2k} \ \sqrt{4-x^2} \ dx \ \rightarrow \ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 2^{2k} \cdot \sin^{2k}\theta \cdot (2 \cos\theta) \cdot (2 \cos\theta \ d\theta )$$

$$= \ 4^{k+1}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \sin^{2k}\theta \   \cos^2\theta \ d\theta \ = \ 4^{k+1}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \sin^{2k} \theta \ - \ \sin^{2k+2} \theta \ d\theta \ ,$$

having applied the Pythagorean Identity in this last stage.  I will use the result (which I won't derive here)

$$ \ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \sin^{2k}\theta \ d\theta \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot \Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+1)} \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot (\frac{2k-1}{2} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sqrt{\pi})}{k!} $$

$$= \ \frac{  ([2k-1] \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 1)}{2^k \cdot k!} \cdot \pi $$

$$\Rightarrow \ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \sin^{2k} \theta \ - \ \sin^{2k+2} \theta \ d\theta \ =  \ [ \frac{  ([2k-1] \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 1)}{2^k \cdot k!}  -  \frac{  ([2k+1] \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 1)}{2^{k+1} \cdot (k+1)!} ] \cdot \pi$$

$$=  \  \frac{[  \ 2(k+1) \ - \ (2k+1) \ ] \cdot ([2k-1] \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 1)}{2^{k+1} \cdot (k+1)!}  \cdot \pi \ = \ \frac{ [2k-1] \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 1}{2^{k+1} \cdot (k+1)!}  \cdot \pi \ .$$

Our original integral is then

$$\int_{-2}^{2} x^{2k} \ \sqrt{4-x^2} \ dx \ = \ 4^{k+1}  \cdot  \frac{ [2k-1] \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 1}{2^{k+1}  \cdot  \ (k+1)!}  \cdot \pi   $$

$$\Rightarrow \ C_k \ = \  \frac{4^{k+1}  \cdot  \frac{ [2k-1] \ \cdot \ [2k-3] \ \cdot \ \ldots \ \cdot \ 3  \ \cdot \ 1}{2^{k+1} \cdot \ (k+1)!}  \cdot \pi}{4^k  \cdot  \frac{ [2k-3] \ \cdot \  \ldots \ \cdot  \ 3 \ \cdot 1}{2^k \ \cdot \ k!}  \cdot \pi} \ = \ \frac{4 \cdot (2k-1)}{2 \cdot (k+1)} \ = \ \frac{2  (2k-1)}{k+1} \ . $$

Answer (score 0):

I like to find the reduction formula for  the integral by rationalization followed by integration by parts.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{k} &=\int_{-2}^{2} x^{2 k} \sqrt{4-x^{2}} d x \\
&=\int_{-2}^{2} \frac{x^{2 k}\left(4-x^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}} d x \\
&=-\int_{-2}^{2} x^{2 k-1}\left(4-x^{2}\right) d\left(\sqrt{4-x^{2}}\right) \\
&=-\left[x^{2 k-1}\left(4-x^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{-2}^{2}+\int_{-2}^{2}\left[4(2 k-1) x^{2 k-2}-(2 k+1) x^{2 k} \right] \sqrt{4-x^2}dx\\
&=4(2 k-1) I_{k-1}-(2 k+1) I_{k} \\\\
I_{k} &=\frac{2(2 k-1)}{k+1} I_{k-1}
\end{aligned} \tag*{} 
\\$$
Hence $C_k= \dfrac{2(2 k-1)}{k+1} .$